# Text processor that supports vertical text for Asian languages (Mac)

Tags: text-editor, word-processor

East Asian languages like Chinese and Japanese are natively and traditionally written in a vertical orientation, top to bottom and right to left. I need this. Problem is the only program that I know of supporting this is Word. I am not a Windows user.

I need a processor or editor, any sort, that supports vertical orientation. It doesn't have to be something like Pages, it could be those more like those markdown processors like Ulysses and iA Writer, or monospace coding apps like Atom for all I care. Or something like Evernote that's not exactly a pure word processor.

Preferably though, I don't want to venture into pdf. Or having to use hack-ish methods like forcing the width.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer question but I've read that Mac's Textedit will do what you need. They have encoding selections including Chinese and Japanese.

Comment: @john unfortunately it's not the encoding that's the problem here. Most if not all software will have UTF-8 encoding, which prints characters properly, but unfortunately it does not change the orientation. We write top to bottom, the world recognizes left to right.

Comment: TextEdit has a setting for top to bottom writing, and I thought with the proper encoding that would work.

Comment: @john wait. WHAT!? I did not know this. Thank you! Puzzles me why it's supported in TextEdit yet not Pages...

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Microsoft Office runs on the Mac. Does the Mac version not support this? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-on-east-asian-language-features-in-office-for-mac-40db0d4f-4bad-47d3-9eeb-bf80f9c3b5b1

Comment: Pages might work too: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH28148?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Macs TextEdit. It has an option to write vertically and encoding for several languages that write that way. TextEdit is free and comes preinstalled on Macs.